# How to handel Preflight request if I don't want to use express cors middleware

Tags: node.js, request, cors, preflight

I'm workding on a login demo page. The login server is different with the authserver.
The main page is runing on localhost:3000 and the login server is runing on localhost:4000
The POST request from main page is blocked by CROS policy.
After some googling. I added Access-Control-Origin header to the response. But browser still says

*Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

The login server code is like this.

```js
app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    let userexist = userinfo.find(user=>user.username===username);
    if (userexist&&password===userexist.password) {
        const accessToken =JWT.sign(username, process.env.accTokenSecret);
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',true);
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type, Accept");
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
        res.status(200).json({'accesstoken':accessToken});
    }else{
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',true)
        res.status(404).json({status:'error',error:'user/password is incorrect'})
    }

});
```

after some more googling I find out that I need to handle the preflight request.So here is my code.

```js
app.options('/login',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',true);
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type, Accept");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.status(200);
});
```

This time, the browser does not show error. But it seems the actual POST request to send username and password did not send after the preflight request.

What did I do wrong? And what should I do if not using cors middleware. Because I'm trying to understand what's actually happend. If using cors middleware. It hide out the details.
Thanks

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` don't go together, because wildcard origins are not allowed in requests with `{credentials: "include"}`.

Answer (score -1):

I find out how to sort this out. Put the function to sent the header in `app.use` block will be able to handle the preflight request and the actual response.

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
  );
  next();
});
```